# $scope not binding inside function in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-platform, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework and am trying to make a request to a service but I am not able to pass the params to the function.

My Html (ionic structure) is as follows:

```
<ion-view view-title="Service Factor" ng-controller="beamdeflectionCtrl">
     <ion-content>
         <div class="item">
             <form novalidate class="col-lg-2">
                 <div class="list">
                     <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                         <span class="input-label">Shaft Length</span>
                         <input type="number" name="itsShaftLength" placeholder="1212" ng-model="itsShaftLength">
                     </label>
                     <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                         <span class="input-label">Running Load</span>
                         <input type="number" placeholder="1212" ng-model="itsRunningLoad">
                     </label>
                     <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                         <span class="input-label">Area Moment Of Inertia</span>
                         <input type="number" placeholder="1212"
                                   ng-model="itsAreaMomentOfInertia">
                     </label>
                     <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                         <span class="input-label">Modulus Of Elasticity</span>
                         <input type="number" placeholder="1212"
                                   ng-model="itsModulusOfElasticity">
                     </label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" ng-click="post()">Get Beam Defection</button>
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
     </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

And my JS file:

```
angular.module('beamdeflection', [])
    .controller('beamdeflectionCtrl', beamdeflectionCtrl,['$scope']);

function beamdeflectionCtrl($stateParams, $scope, $http, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.post = function () {
        $http({
            url: "/myurl",
            method: "GET",
            params: {
                shaftLength: $scope.itsShaftLength,//I am not getting this value
                runningLoad:$scope.itsRunningLoad,//I am not getting this value
                areaMomentOfInertia: $scope.itsAreaMomentOfInertia,//I am not getting this value
                modulusOfElasticity:$scope.itsModulusOfElasticity//I am not getting this value
            }}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Beam Deflection Calculated',
                    template: data
                });
                $scope.data = data;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Beam Deflection Failed',
                    template: data
                });
            });
        };
    };
}
```

For some reason `$scope.itsShaftLength` and other params inside the post function are not getting values. The debugger states that they are undefined. I am new to angular. I wonder if I missed something in my code. Moreover, I tried passing $scope to the function as `$scope.post = function ($scope){....` but it yells at me saying "$scope not defined". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: okay i am  a Little confused the data from the success function should contain the information you want to show in the ionic alert right? 2nd thing i noticed i dont think you can pass the return Data to the alert you can only use template with a string and templateUrl for a html file or smth so id suggest var string = data.something and then pass the string in the template

Comment: @stackg91 Yes it is. However, I am not giving the service proper data (but bunch of unknowns) and it is bombing out.

Comment: doesn't make sense that `$scope.post` is making a GET request

Comment: not sure if this is the reason but don't your input field need "name"? i see that not all of them have it

Comment: @charlietfl yeah, a studip backend developer implemented it as get and params.

Comment: well how the function is called is not important dont use data as template for ionic.alert

Comment: @GY22 do I need to put name? I have never done that before!

Comment: also...always use a `dot` in `ng-model` to take advantage of inheritance. Since you are using primitives likely getting lost in child scopes

Comment: als i  believe your missing quotes in your params ->  params: {
                'shaftLength': $scope.itsShaftLength,//I am not getting this value
                'runningLoad':$scope.itsRunningLoad,//I am not getting this value
                'areaMomentOfInertia': $scope.itsAreaMomentOfInertia,//I am not getting this value
                'modulusOfElasticity':$scope.itsModulusOfElasticity//I am not getting this value
            }}).

Comment: @GY22 can you clarify what are you trying to say?

Comment: @GY22 quotes are optional for object keys that don't contain special characters. That is a non issue here

Comment: @GY22 well that shouldn't matter. Just `$scope.itsShaftLength` is undefined that is the problem.

Comment: @DineshDevkota, sorry if I am not very clear. also very new to angular. just wanted to help out. check this question i asked not so long ago -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026997/saving-data-to-db-with-angularjs-and-php. maybe it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really not define your ng-models in $scope on your code. You can do something like this:

```
 $scope.post = function (data) {
    $http({
        url: "/myurl",
        method: "GET",
        params: {
            shaftLength: data.itsShaftLength,
            runningLoad: data.itsRunningLoad,
            areaMomentOfInertia: data.itsAreaMomentOfInertia,
            modulusOfElasticity: data.itsModulusOfElasticity            }})... more code...
```

In your html you define at all inputs ng-model:

```
<input type="number" name="itsShaftLength" placeholder="1212" ng-model="data.itsShaftLength"> ...
```

And on ng-click:

```
ng-click="post(data)"
```

Comment: Alrighty. This works. I was missing to use dot notation and tried passing $scope rather than object itself. Thank you.

Comment: You're Welcome. I recommend to you take some time to read AngularJs and Ionic docs (and they are pretty easy to learn).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment you should always use objects in `ng-model` since binding of primitives gets broken in child scopes.

General rule of thumb:  ***always have a dot in ng-model***

Try changing all the `ng-model` to have an object prefix and a dot

```
<input ng-model="formData.itsModulusOfElasticity">
```

In controller define that object:

```
$scope.formData={};
```

This also simplifies what you need to send as params since all the form data is already contained in one object:

```
 params: angular.copy($scope.formData) // using "copy" strips out any angular properties
```

Start here for further reading and make sure to read about angular scopes

[Why don't the AngularJS docs use a dot in the model directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)

Comment: Well, I was able to pass values now. Is there way to Isolate each params values from formData?. Server didn't really like it. I am saying so because once I initialized the values and it works with it.

Comment: note minor change I added with angular copy. Be more specific about `server doesn't take it`. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools to see what is sent

Comment: I meant when I sent them as params( after initializing it for testing) with each `shaftLength`, `runningLoad`,`areaMomentOfInertia` and `modulusOfElasticity` separated and not as whole formData object and that works fine.

Comment: that doesn't explain the problem...did you inspect the actual request in network tab to see what was sent?

Comment: Yes, I did. It makes URL request by concatenating the parameters in URL and that is not allowed in back-end.

Comment: but that's what a GET request does. Should really be using POST. SInce you selected other answer ...should follow up any further issues with them

Comment: you have an upvote from me. Very nicely answered. There is something weird going on in my backed.